# How to get AssetBundleManifest in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, hash, assetbundle

Following the instructions on the official site https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching.html I fail to get `AssetBundleManifest` neither from the server nor from local storage. The end goal is to get `AssetBundle`’s hash.

Main error message in the console is:

> Failed to decompress data for the AssetBundle "Memory"

I tried to use the following:

`UnityWebRequest` - to load from server

`LoadFromFile` - to local from local storage

How to do it correctly?